# Problemas com imagem ao utilizar include

Tags: url, diretório, include, img

estou desenvolvendo um site e depois de desenvolver a maioria dos arquivos, resolvi organiza-los em suas respectivas pastas.

localhost/nomedosite/   -- pasta raiz 
localhost/nomedosite/includes/  -- pasta onde estão navs, barras administrativas, rodapés 
localhost/nomedosite/uploads/ -- pasta contendo uploads de imagens 
localhost/nomedosite/includes/adminbar.php -- essa barra administrativa, possui em seu código, um trecho php com echo de uma url guardada no banco de dados. 
localhost/nomedosite/restrito/ -- pasta onde estão os arquivos para usuários de acesso restrito  
localhost/nomedosite/restrito/inicio.php -- página inicial para usuários logados.

Bom, o erro que estou enfrentando é o seguinte, uma vez que eu coloquei os arquivos nas novas pastas, as imagens pararam de aparecer e quando eu vou verificar a url delas, a url que eu recebo é a seguinte:

restrito/uploads/imgs/users/4153eb08425b193e0092b9cbeb509d62.jpg

Sendo que o que está é:

/uploads/imgs/users/4153eb08425b193e0092b9cbeb509d62.jpg

Ou seja, o arquivo "puxa" o caminho da pasta atual, esse erro ocorre apenas quando os arquivos estão nas subpastas, quando todos os arquivos estavam na pasta raiz, nenhum erro aparecia.

Comment: A pasta "uploads" está dentro da pasta "restrito" ou na raiz?!

Comment: está dentro da raiz @DavidSam, ou seja, está uma pasta "acima"

Comment: Se está uma pasta cima, então o src da imagem deveria ser src="../uploads/imgs/users/4153eb08425b193e0092b9cbeb509d62.jpg". Com "../" antes.

Comment: Sim sim, eu entendo! no entanto, isso não resolveria meu problema, pois o arquivo que exibe está imagem é um arquivo que está na pasta include, e ele deveria supostamente funcionar em qualquer pasta do sistema, entende o problema? 
Eu poderia resolver o problema colocando "../" porém iria funcionar apenas nesta pasta em específico

Comment: @DavidSam Essa imagem está dentro de um arquivo da pasta /include. 
Imagina que eu crio mais uma subpasta para a pasta /restrito .. e faço o include do arquivo com o a imagem, o "../" não seria suficiente, teriam que ser dois "../../" ou seja, eu preciso de uma solução que resolva isso em qualquer circunstância

Comment: Neste caso acho q vc deve incluir no src da imagem um caminho via script do servidor: src="<?php caminho_fisico_do_servidor ?>/uploads/imgs/users/4153eb08425b193e0092b9cbeb509d62.‌​jpg"

Comment: Eu acho que entendi. Você tem que carregar a imagem com um caminho único não importa qual pasta a página está. No meu comentário anterior não iria funcionar pegar o caminho físico do servidor.

Comment: Eu acho que resolveria fazer comparações tipo: se a página está numa subpasta X, então "../" ou se está numa Y, então "../../"

Comment: @DavidSam Resolvi o problema com caminho absoluto, no arquivo que está na pasta include/ .. eu escrevi : echo "https://localhost/nomedosite/". $url_da_imagem; e Resolveu. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!